# Jquery Offset property not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, offset

I have a problem with a drag and drop in Internet Explorer.

I am changing the offset() of an object in the mousemove handler:

```
this.target.offset({
    left: e.pageX - this.target.outerWidth(true) / 2,
    top: e.pageY - this.target.outerHeight(true) / 2
})
```

It is all working on every browser except IE. This is part of a bigger project with other JS files and I have identified the file that does this. But i can't modify it also I don't really understand what it does there and why?

The part of the code that I have identified responsible is:

```
$.browser.msie && ($.fn.position = function () {
        return {
            left: this[0].offsetLeft,
            top: this[0].offsetTop
        }
    }, $.fn.offset = function () {
        var e = this[0],
            t = 0,
            n = 0;
        do t += e.offsetLeft, n += e.offsetTop; while (e = e.offsetParent);
        return {
            left: t,
            top: n
        }
    });
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What versions of IE do you use?

Comment: Make sure running in real IE10 mode, not any compatibility mode or quirks mode

Comment: Are you using JQueryUI 1.8.6 or older ?

Comment: Yes I am running in IE 10 real. And yes using jquery-1.8.3.js. I am not using jQuery UI...just jQuery I don't want to use UI. As far as I can see they are overriding the offset function from  but I don't know why and how to fix it without altering their code from the framework.

Comment: Can you try with jsFiddle and check if the problems occurs on JQuery 1.8. Then try with 1.9 or more and check if it resolves your problem.

Comment: The problems is not from jQuery it is from another JS file from the framework we use which as far as i see overrides the $.fn.offset. I was more curios what that override does and why. The solution i think is to save the original definition of the function in a variable and use it when I need it but I don't know why they have overridden the definition. So in case haven't been clear the second part of the code is a custom code from a custom framework we use not from jQuery and it overrides the definition from jQuery.